# Custom stage directory with Capistrano

Tags: ruby, deployment, capistrano

How to change the default loading stage directory `deploy/{mystage}.rb`
to something like `../../mystages/{mystage}.rb`

with the multistage extension ?

```
set :stages, %w(stage1 stage2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, you'll define custom stages, as you quoted, with

```
set :stages, %w(stage1 stage2)
```

Capistrano will expect to find `stage1.rb` and `stage2.rb` under *deploy/*

However, it looks like an additional directive (`stage_dir`) was merged, see the commit [here](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/pull/475)